# Selecting last inserted id and inserting into second table in MY SQL

Tags: mysql

I am new to my sql and got stuck in a query. The query I am using is as follows;

```
insert into tableA(fname, lname) values('hello','world');
@id=SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
insert into tableB(x,y) values('good', @id);
```

but i am getting an error below;

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@id=SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()' at line 2
```

please somebody suggest what is wrong I am doing here, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close.

```
insert into tableA(fname, lname) values('hello','world');
SET @id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
insert into tableB(x,y) values('good', @id);
```

Result:

```
mysql> insert into tableA(fname, lname) values('hello','world');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> SET @id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Sorry. That's what I get for copy and pasting your code without a coffee first. I've edited my answer, remove the 'SELECT' from the SET statement!!

Comment: What should "Close" mean? Please add some more relevant information to your answer, like a link to the documentation.

Comment: Not close as in 'make not open', but close as in, you're very nearly right :)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `set`

```
insert into tableA(fname, lname) values('hello','world');
set @id=SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
insert into tableB(x,y) values('good', @id);
```